# Is there an analytical solution for this equation?

Tags: logarithms, trigonometry

Can this equation be solved using an analytical approach?

$$
\frac{\tan(x+4)}{\log_{10}(x+\frac{1}{4})}+12x = 0
$$

It's easy to approximate the solutions using a [graphical approach](https://www.google.com/search?q=tan%28x%2B4%29%2Flog%28x%2B1%2F4%29%2B12x), but I'd like to know if it can also be solved analytically.

Comment: The moment you mix `log` with `x` I think all analytical solutions are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28tan%28x+%2B+4%29%2Flog_10%28x+%2B+%281%2F4%29%29%29+%2B+12x+%3D+0)?

The query returns the roots:
$$x_1 \approx 1.16050098312550430340684691016547285734$$
$$x_2 \approx 3.88870717165940424459231171773335251316$$
$$x_3 \approx 7.00938317785685608917507135799963829506$$
$$x_4 \approx 10.1452448027782739292083257806596244630.$$

After seeing the numerical solutions, I would guess there is no analytical solution, but I may be wrong.